# Проблема с событиями

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть контрол. У него я обрабатываю событие `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`. В этом контроле есть Button. Когда делаю клик по кнопочке, сначала срабатывает `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` контрола. Как сделать так, чтобы событие `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` на контроле обрабатывалось только в том случае, если нажатие было не на кнопке?

Answer (score 2):

Туннелирование события работает с верхних уровней до нижнего, это стандартное поведение. Если вы не хотите обрабатывать событие, просто пропустите его, проверив источник события в контроле верхнего уровня.

```
if((sender as Button) != null) return;
```

В этом случае и Ваш код не выполнится в контроле и событие пройдет дальше к кнопке.

**UPD:** Все, я вроде понял, не правильно понял вопрос изначально. Вам просто надо проверить был ли под курсором дочерний элемент из обработчика верхнего элемента.

```
private void control_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = e.GetPosition(child);
    if (VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(child, point) != null) return;

    ....
}
```

В данном случае в коде child - ваша кнопка внутри контрола.

Comment: наверно лучше **if (sender is Button) return;**

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, ну можно и так))

Comment: у меня sender - тот самый элемент, а не кнопочка

Comment: @iRumba: А `Source` или `OriginalSource`?

Comment: `source` - тот же контрол. `OriginalSource` - TextBlock :)

Comment: И откуда мне брать этот `child`? Контролов то с этими кнопками много, размножаются из коллекции биндингом

Comment: При попытке перехватить событие `Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, обнаружил, что сначала такое событие выполняется на родительском контроле. Не знаю, правда, почему. Разве оно должно распространяться не с глубины к корню?

Comment: @iRumba, откуда брать child это уже вопрос к тому, как Ваше приложение устроено, что бы в нем это реализовать. По-поводу второго, в том и дело, что WPF поддерживает как всплывающие(с глубины к корню), так и туннелированные события(от корня к источнику). Практически все события preview являются туннелированными. Если у Вас есть возможность использовать просто MouseLeftButtonDown, то воспользуйтесь им, повесьте как на кнопку так и на контрол после чего в кнопке прервите через e.Handled = true;

Comment: Я пытался делать без Preview, в этом случае событие не доходит до нужного контрола, так как на самом деле я кликаю по контенту (коим может являться `TextBlock`, например) и дальше событие не проходит. Приложение устроено так, что кнопочка находится в `ContentTemplate`. То есть таких кнопочек ровно столько, сколько нужных мне контролов и они не создаются в Initialize.